# Is it possible to get symlinks in a mounted folder or another link to resolve to the remote side rather than the local side?

Tags: macos, unix, symlink

I've attempted to mount a nfs network share on another computer that has symlinks in it. When I try t cd into that dir, they are resolved on the local side (so I get a not found error). Is it possible to do this so they are followed on the remote side?

This is on OS X, so there might be another way to do this (AFP perhaps), or creating a OS X Alias (although I don't think the unix subsystem recognises there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way out is to mount the NFS share in the same place as on the system where the symlinks work.

Another way would be to change the symlinks to relative ones, if you have the necessary control. There are reasons why many applications create symlinks with lots of `../../../` prefixes, and this situation is one of them.

If you can't do that, you might be able to finesse it if you don't need 'any random symlink' to work.

For instance, if the symlinks that you want to resolve all point into one or a few specific directories that don't exist on the local side, you can symlink those back to the mounted file system.

Simple example: You've mounted `remote:/var/usr` as `/mnt/remote-usr`, and you really want the symlinks into `/var/usr/myapp` to work: Just symlink `var/usr/myapp` to `/mnt/remote-usr/myapp` on the local side, and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic links know nothing about "local" or "remote" side.  They are simply special files  containing a path that is automatically interpreted by the operating system when accessed.

Comment: I understand that. I wondering if there is an alternative to symlinks that will link to the remote side. Sorry, I think my question wasn't exactly clear on that point :)